# C# Hide cursor while allowing mouse events to pass through a transparent window

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, mouseevent, transparency

I'm using this code to make fullscreen window transparent and allow mouse event to pass through that window:

```
Cursor.Hide();
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.White;
int initialStyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20);
SetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20, initialStyle | 0x80000 | 0x20);
```

but now when the window is transparent **Cursor.Hide();** is not working any more... How to fix this?

Comment: are you using other controls ,,like panel inside your form?

Comment: No, it's blank window.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a "blank" cursor, and set

`myForm.Cursor = blankCursor;`

This will make that specific form show a specific cursor, which could be completely transparent.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Cursor does not contain a definiton for 'None'.

Comment: @mgulan sorry...i am confusing with wpf